# Is it possible to change if statement syntax in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm new at C# Programming, I just wanna ask if is it possible to change if, else statement syntax in C#?

Example:

Instead of :

```
    a=5;
    b=6;
    if (a<b)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Big");
    }
    else
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Small");
}//Output is Small
```

I would like to change **if else statement syntax** to other words:

```
 a=5;
    b=6;
    **say** (a<b)// say is "if"
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Big");
    }
    **but**// but is "else"
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Small");
}//Output is Small
```

I wanna type it in the textbox and display it in the label
How to do this?

I'm hoping for your help, thank you.

Comment: _AFAIK_ you can't do that. Even if you _can_, don't :)

Comment: what does AFAIK means?

Comment: It'd be wonderful if the difference between `C` and `C#` would be just usage of `#`

Comment: @Neel It means [as far as I know](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/afaik)

Comment: oh sorry for silly question @SonerGönül

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't change the syntax of C#. It's baked into the language.

Of course, you could check out the Roslyn compiler and build your own "not quite C#" compiler... but I'd *strongly* advise against it. Why would you want to create a language which no-one but yourself knows how to use, and which has no real advantages over C# other than using a very slightly different vocabulary? You wouldn't be adding anything to the expressive power of the language by doing so.

Comment: You don't need to know the Roslyn compiler, there is always '#define' and the C preprocessor (you'd probably have to use makefiles though). But as you suggest, why do this? It doesn't add anything apart from obsfucation and complexity.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is `NO`. You can not achieve this using c#.

And I would suggest why you want to change it I mean its already nicely readable if it is the reason.
And even if you able to do it then also it is not recommended to change the default syntax because it will create confusion for your follow developers.

**Extra Note** :-

One of the c# operators i tend to use a lot is the ?: operator which is essentially an alternative syntax to an if else statement.

**Syntax** :

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if (condition) {
 first_expression;
}
else {
 second_expression;
}
```

Comment: It's just an assignment, we have to make a syntax analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot in C#

In C and C++ by using Macros `#define` you can acheive what you are trying to do. But in C# it donot contain any Macros because

> One of main design goals for C# is to keep the code very readable.
>   Having the ability to write macros gives the programmer the ability to
>   create their own language - one that doesn't necessarily bear any
>   relation to what the code underneath. To understand what the code
>   does, the user must not only understand how the language works, but he
>   must also understand all of the #define macros that are in effect at
>   that point in time. That makes code much harder to read.

Comment: Technically, you can use macros in C#, you just have to forego the IDE and create a makefile/or whatever. So you end up doing: text file -> preprocessor -> compiler -> linker -> executable. It isn't easy but can be done. The preprocessor could be an interpreter for the languge you're using / making up, a bit like the first C++ parsers.

Answer (score 0):

No. if and else structure persists in many programming languages, so it is accepted globally. I strongly advise not do so.

Answer (score 0):

I have not understood exactly what you want to achieve but maybe you mean the following

```
Console.WriteLine( a < b ? "Big" : "Small" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read more related to Expression Trees, this provides you with creating code in runtime , then compile and execute. This way your problem can be solved.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx